# Construir array con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Soy nuevo en el desarrollo de JavaScript, estoy realizando mi app web ASP.NET MVC 5 y requiero de una funcionalidad en JS:

Cada vez que ingresan datos a mi función SD_Ejemplo (contiene 8 datos que en una fila de un registro) quisiera almacenarlos en un array y así sucesivamente de acuerdo a las variables que recibe.

En resumen quisiera guardar datos de varias filas ingresadas a mi función en un array.

Adjunto de la función base que estoy contruyendo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function SD_Ejemplo( 
    CO_EMPR, TI_REQI, NU_REQI, NU_SECU, 
    CO_ITEM, CA_SOLI, CA_ATEN, CA_PEND,
    Item_Seleccionado
  ) {
  //Recibir y almacenar en un arreglo ...
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo como esto, pero tu recibiento todos los campos que necesitas 
Usar un array global y un contador para ir aumentando la posición

```js
let array = []; // array para guardar datos

let count = 0;
function SD_Ejemplo(CO_EMPR, TI_REQI) {
          var Existe =false;
          var i;
          for (i=0;i<array.length;i++)
          {
            if (array[i].CO_EMPRField==CO_EMPR && array[i].TI_REQField==TI_REQI)
            {
              Existe=true;

                break;
            }
          }
          if (Existe)
            {
              console.log('Ese registro ya existe se procedera a eliminarlo');
               //Se borra del arreglo
              array.splice(i,1);
            }
            else 
            {
                console.log('Ese no existe');
                 array[count] = { CO_EMPRField: CO_EMPR,TI_REQField:TI_REQI };
                   count++;//Aumentamos
            }           
 };
 //insertamos 4 veces
SD_Ejemplo(1,32);
SD_Ejemplo(2,45);
SD_Ejemplo(3,56);
SD_Ejemplo(4,78);
//Comprobamos que hay 4 valores
console.log(array);
//Repetimos para insertar uno que ya esta
SD_Ejemplo(4,78);
//Comprobamos que solo quedan 3
console.log(array);
```

Saludos

Comment: Me funcionó perfecto, una consulta adicional si con esos 4 elementos que ingresan (de la respuesta superior) como puedo hacer para ubicar la ubicación index en el array si ingresan datos "1,32" esto con finalidad que si ya existe no ingresarlo nuevamente o eliminarlo si ingresan los mismos datos en el array.

Comment: Hola prueba con algo como esto.
const resultado = array.find( arr => arr.CO_EMPRField == 1 && arr.TI_REQField==32 );

console.log(resultado);

Comment: Pero para ese caso debería igualarlo con buscar el elemento dentro del array, veo que lo igualas ==1 && ==2

Comment: Te edito la respuesta con lo nuevo que me solicitas .

Answer (score 0):

Lo podrías hacer así, primero declaras las variables la de datos es la que guarda toda la iformación que obtienes de la función, la otra variable info es la que rellena la informacion en el array.

```
var datos = [];
var info = {};

function SD_Ejemplo(CO_EMPR, TI_REQI) {
 info.Co_empr = CO_EMPR
 info.ti_req = TI_REQI
 datos.push(info)
 info = {} //limpiar
}
```

Ya nada más agregas los demás parámetros que necesites y ya.